# REGEX python find previous string

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm trying to find if the last word of the string is followed by a space or a special char, and if yes return the string without this space/special char

For example :

```
"do you love dogs ?" ==> return "do you love dogs"
"i love my dog " (space after dog) ==> return "i love my dog"
"do you love dogs?"  ==> return "do you love dogs"
```

So far I tried :

```
re.search(re.compile(r"^[^\,\(\[\.\!\?]*"), mystring)
```

It works in the last example but not in the first two (it keeps the space of the second example) and I don't know how to deal with it.

EDIT : the special chars are : '.', '!', '?', '(', '[',',' at first then every other non numeric/alphabetical except those

Comment: Your last example makes no sense at all.

Comment: You should correct your third example.

Comment: You don't need a regex: `mystring.rstrip(' .?!')`

Comment: i corrected the third example !

Comment: @Mauris : i can't as i have to use it as a if statement first like : 
if (the string is terminated by a space or "space + special char" or special char --> return the part of the string before these special chars

Comment: You write "have to" -- is this a homework assignment? Also, you should specify what a "special char" is. What if a string ends in two spaces?

Comment: @Mauris : no it is not a homework assignment.

the special char are : ., !, ?, (, [      at first then every other non numeric/alphabetical except those

Comment: Use `re` makes it complicated, you can just store the last string and update it when **special case**

Comment: If there's no external force telling you to use an `if`, then there's no reason to limit yourself to this approach. Can you show me a case where `mystring.rstrip(' .?!')` gives the wrong result?

Comment: What do you mean by "at first ... then ..."? Are the sets of "special chars" different for the cases *space + special char* and *special char*? Or do you need a solution that you can expand later?

Comment: @Mauris: at first : in a if ; then : later in the code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Updated:  This will check for the existence of a sentence followed by special characters. It returns false if there are no special characters, and your original sentence is in capture group 1.

[Updated Regex101 Example](https://regex101.com/r/rE2fB5/5)

```
r"(.*[\w])([^\w]+)"
```

Alternatively (without a second capture group):

[Regex101 Example - no second capture group](https://regex101.com/r/rE2fB5/6)

```
r"(.*[\w])(?:[^\w]+)"
```

That's what you're looking for right?

Comment: Yup, regex101 and regexr are great places to learn regex better and test this kinda stuff.  I recommend spending some time there.

Comment: Actually i need the regex to be able to detect the special char because i need to use it in a if statement

Comment: Oh, I see I skimmed too quickly, I thought you were just grabbing the internal string.

Comment: I added 2 capture groups now, you basically want to keep the first one, and it will only return true if there ARE special characters at the end of the string, which is captured in the second capture group.  Alternatively you could make it a non capturing group as well.

Comment: No problem, regex is fun. :)

Comment: when i try with "me too" it doesnt work, it should capture nothing... but here it capture "me"... any help ??

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the space and the special char from the end of those 3 sentences, using regex, this is one way you can do it:

```
import re

print re.findall(r'\w+\s\w+\s\w+\s\w+', "i love my dog ")
print re.findall(r'\w+\s\w+\s\w+\s\w+', "do you love dogs ?")
print re.findall(r'\w+\s\w+\s\w+\s\w+', "do you love dogs?")
```

Output:

```
['i love my dog']
['do you love dogs']
['do you love dogs']
```